# Second ejs file not picking data Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

So, basically I am trying to link two ejs files to express. The first one gets connected and displays result but second one that comes after pressing a button on first one shows error.

[image]

The `user-list` file displays results correctly but the exact same table code shows error in `parks`

`parks.ejs` (when I click the link in `user-list` that redirects here, it says `userData` not defined)

```
<div class="table-data">
        <h2>Display Data using Node.js & MySQL</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Station N</th>
                    
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
                
                <%
                if(userData.length!=0){
                var i=1;
                userData.forEach(function(data){
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=i; %></td>
                    <td><%=data.Station %></td>
                    
                    <td><a href="/users/edit/<%=data.id%>">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="/users/delete/<%=data.id%>">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <%  i++; }) %>
                <% } else{ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="7">No Data Found</td>
                    </tr>
                <% } %>
            </table>
            </div>
```

`user-list.ejs`

```
<a href="/parks"> hello</a>
++the table code shown above
```

`users.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../database');



router.get('/user-list', function(req, res, next) {

    db.query("SELECT Station_ID FROM Station WHERE Name = 'A'", function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('user-list', { title: 'User List', userData: results});
  });
});

router.get('/parks', function(req, res, next) {                //this part not working

    db.query("SELECT Station_ID FROM Station WHERE Name = 'A'", function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('parks', { title: 'User Listt', userData: results});
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Worth noting is the `app.js` file because there I had to add `app.get("/parks"` line to link the two pages otherwise even the link didn't redirect to parks.ejs

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const ejs = require('ejs'); 

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.get("/parks", function(req,res){
  res.render("parks");
});


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="/parks"> hello</a>
```

Here, the url is relative to the document root, so this will trigger your `app.get("/parks")` route handler - which actually doesn't seem to provide a `userData` variable.

If you want to trigger the `router.get('/parks')` handler from your user router, you should use a url relative to the current path.

```
<a href="parks"> hello</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/users/parks"> hello</a>
```

Comment: So, is the `app.get` any necessary

Comment: It depends on whether you actually want to serve the parks template at the /parks path. If so and you actually do not provide `userData` a value, the parks template should include some sanity checks before trying to access its `length` or `forEach()` properties.